# Ruby Nokogiri SAX parsing string too long

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have written a SAX parser using Nokogiri in Ruby and I am parsing a very large xml file.
The strange thing is that, using

```
data.each do |node| 
    if (node.name == "product" && node.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Reader::TYPE_ELEMENT)
    #puts p.inspect
    p = Nokogiri::XML.parse(node.outer_xml)

    #puts p.xpath("//xmlns:step-quantity").text


    images = []
    sizes = []
    colors = []

    # If product is a master
    if p.xpath('//xmlns:image-group[@view-type="re_detail"]/xmlns:image/@path').count != 0
        # Product ID
        product_id = p.xpath('//@product-id').text # <--- THIS
```

returns

```
hbeu5010140440462983591054046298359112404629835912940462983591364046298359143404629835915040462983591674046298359174
```

for XML

```
  <product product-id="hbeu50101404">
    <ean/>
    <upc/>
    <unit/>
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
```

I don't understand why?
I would just cut the string length but some IDs are longer and I find that kind of dirty.
Can somebody help me please? :-)

Thanks in advance

Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the answer is simple: I had other attributes with a `product-id="hbeu50101404"` like a `<variation>`, that is why it collected everything in the string -.-

Comment: Use `at_xpath` or just `at` if you want only the first result instead of a NodeSet (array-like) collection of results.

Comment: Your're right @Phrogz, totally blacked out on this one! Thanks for adding this!